# Calling UNRAR.exe using system in c++

Tags: c++, windows, system

I am trying to run a very simple console application in VC2010, and I cannot successfully pass parameters to unrar.exe using system function. The application is intended to find the password for a RAR file which I have forgotten. Here is the main file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
#include <direct.h>
#include "Password.h"
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;


string RARPath  = "\"UnRAR.exe\"";
string FP2 = "\"C:\\Program Files\\WINRAR\\RU.rar\"";
string Access = "runas /user:NimaNikvand ";
string Destination = "\"C:\\Tester\\Extracted\"";

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{

    for(int Passlength=2;Passlength<50;Passlength++)
    {
        Password pass(Passlength);
        for(int i=0;i<pow(pass.AlphaBeta.size()*1.0,Passlength);i++)
        {
            time_t t1 = clock();
            pass.IncrementalSweep();
            cout<<"Trying Password: "<<pass.GetPass()<<endl;;
            string Command =RARPath+" x"+" -p\""+pass.GetPass()+"\" "+FP2+" *.* "+Destination;
            cout<<Command<<endl;
            _chdir("C:\\Program Files\\WINRAR\\");
            int flag = system(Command.c_str());
            time_t t2 = clock();
            cout<<"SPEED: "<<(CLOCKS_PER_SEC)/(1.0*t2-1.0*t1)<<" PASSWORDS Per Second"<<endl;

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Everything works fine and the pass object keeps getting updated incrementally using functions in its class definition, however when I run the final build, I get the following in Command: "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect". And Yes I have tried the exact Command format manually in cmd and it works perfectly fine. I don't intend to use shellexecute or a fancy createprocess API and need to keep this a simple console application.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: My crystal ball says that your 32-bit build is using `c:\program files (x86)\winrar` as the default directory.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Hans. I am telling the program to run the one in {_chdir("C:\\Program Files\\WINRAR\\");} . It is strange as I can call exactly the same command from MATLAB with no problem. I don't have a 32 bit version of RAR installed.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: remove the trailing slashes from the directory name in _chdir() call:

```
_chdir("C:\\Program Files\\WinRAR");
```

Explanations:  To figure out such errors it is useful to inspect the `errno` value (#include ). The value 22 indicates invalid parameters.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is not a compile or linker error. The program runs fine, except when the console application is running I am getting the following answer in cmd: "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect". Also I tried the following: _chdir("C:\Program Files\WINRAR\\");  with no success

Comment: I mean _chdir("C:\\Program Files\\WINRAR");